# macでipv6環境を作成して、iosでsockaddr_inを利用しても動作してしまう

Tags: ios, ipv6

ipv6検証をするために[ios Developer CenterのTest for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)を参考にipv6環境をmacに作りました。

[Qiita](http://qiita.com/yonell/items/16c08e541b4a2b84b0a3)でも同様のやり方が書かれていました。

そして、以下のコードで検証しようとしました。

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];
```

以下が該当の[Reachabilityのソース](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.m#L122)です。

```
+(instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection {
  struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
  bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
  zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
  zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

  return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
}

+(instancetype)reachabilityWithAddress:(void *)hostAddress {
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*)hostAddress);

   if (ref) 
    {
     id reachability = [[self alloc] initWithReachabilityRef:ref];
     return reachability;
    }

   return nil;
}
```

sockaddr_inはipv4用なので動作しないはずと考えていましたが、ios9.3.1で動作させたところ、普通に動作してしまいました。
(参考までに[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/3174/files)のipv6対応を見ると `sockaddr_in6` に変えていていました。)

なぜ動作してしまうのか、教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

推測ですが、AppleのReachabilityのサンプルソースのReadme
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_md.html
には、

> IPv6 Support
>
> Reachability fully supports IPv6.  More specifically, each of the APIs >handles IPv6 in the following way:
>
> reachabilityForInternetConnection
>
> This monitors the address 0.0.0.0, which reachability treats as a >special token that causes it to actually monitor the general routing >status of the device, both IPv4 and IPv6

とあるので、IPv4ではReachしないけど、IPv6でReachしているからOKということですかね。

iOS9.3.1でreachabilityWithAddressでIPv4アドレスリテラルを使うと失敗しますね。

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_len = INET_ADDRSTRLEN;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"); // ここは適当な0.0.0.0でない有効なグローバルIPを入れる
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&addr];
[reachability startNotifier];
NSLog(@"reachable[%d]", reachability.currentReachabilityStatus); // ipv6環境では、NotReachableで、ipv4環境ではReachableViaWiFiになります
```

他のバージョンでは試してません。

この辺も見ておいた方が良さそうです。

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3498

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
reachabilityForInternetConnectionでは、(0埋めしてIPv4用のAF_INETの定義を利用して)IPv4アドレスリテラルを作って、reachabilityWithAddressを呼び出しています。
なので、行っていることは同じだと思うのですが、どのように記述したら失敗しましたか？具体的なソースを記述していただくと助かります。

Comment: 試したソースを追記してみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！有効なグローバルアドレスを使えば動作しないことを確認できました。

Comment: 回答を質問に合わせたソースに変更しましたので宜しくお願いします。